# I want to display the line content after the match using grep

Tags: unix

I have the content in log file s below:

```
Aug 02 22:01:18.0937 CDT Thread-4-610399 java.lang.IllegalStateException: perfdb_connectstring was not found in the supplied property file(s).
```

I want the output to be `java.lang.IllegalStateException: perfdb_connectstring was not found` in the supplied property file(s) using grep command.

Please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use 'grep'? If the log file always has this format maybe you should use 'cut'

```
cut -d" " -f6- file.log
```

It will output exactly what you want to stdout:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: perfdb_connectstring was not found in the supplied property file(s).
```